# playing .mov in flash

Tags: flash, movie

Can i stream .mov in a flash player . I'm looking for a relatively easy option 
h.264

Comment: since 2007 you can: http://aralbalkan.com/1012

Answer (score 0):

Use the FLVPlaybackComponent and choose your .mov file as the source, should work fine

Answer (score 0):

`.mov` is a container for a ton of possible codecs (like `.avi`). If its an MPEG-4 derived codec, playback should work correctly, however its not guaranteed.